# new String(bytes) won't work in gradle

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, groovy

I was trying to read the output data from shell using

```
def cmd = "adb shell echo \$EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
def proc = cmd.execute()
println proc.in.text
```

and it turned out to be nothing in gradle while I tried that code simply in groovy script, it worked.

finally I found out that the problem should be new String(bytes), the code below works in groovy script but not in gradle.

```
byte[] bytes = [47, 115, 116, 111, 114, 97, 103, 101, 47, 101, 109, 117, 108, 97, 116, 101, 100, 47, 108, 101, 103, 97, 99, 121, 13, 10]
println new String(bytes)
```

Anyone could tell me what happened? Really annoying...

-----------update-------------------

I tried the code by @JBirdVegas, it seems to be caused by Android Studio, version 2.2.3 stable. I also tried

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3
Build #IU-163.11103.6, built on January 17, 2017
Licensed to Benny Huo
Subscription is active until August 6, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

and still the same as before.

Unlike the output in command line, when you trigger the gradle task in gradle panel of those IDE, :

[image]

If you choose a Charset of UTF_8, US_ASCII or ISO_8859_1, you will see nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I find out that those bytes contains a '\r'(13), when printed to the console, the content of the whole line is cleared, so that nothing can be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working for me but I suspect this is a issue with `Charset`.

Using the emulator on my Mac I see the following

```
tasks.create('testAdb') {
    def cmd = "adb shell echo \$EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    def proc = cmd.execute()
    print "cmd result: $proc.in.text"
    byte[] bytes = [47, 115, 116, 111, 114, 97, 103, 101, 47, 101, 109, 117, 108, 97, 116, 101, 100, 47, 108, 101, 103, 97, 99, 121, 13, 10]
    print "new String bytes (with default charset): ${new String(bytes, Charset.defaultCharset())}"
    println "default charset: ${Charset.defaultCharset()}"
    print "new String bytes: ${new String(bytes)}"
    print "new String bytes (with UTF-8 charset): ${new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)}"
    println "new String bytes (with UTF-16 charset): ${new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_16)}"
    println "new String bytes (with UTF-16BE charset): ${new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE)}"
    println "new String bytes (with UTF-16LE charset): ${new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE)}"
    print "new String bytes (with US_ASCII charset): ${new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)}"
    print "new String bytes (with ISO_8859_1 charset): ${new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)}"
}


$ ./gradlew testAdb -q
cmd result: /sdcard
new String bytes (with default charset): /storage/emulated/legacy
default charset: UTF-8
new String bytes: /storage/emulated/legacy
new String bytes (with UTF-8 charset): /storage/emulated/legacy
new String bytes (with UTF-16 charset): ⽳瑯牡来⽥浵污瑥搯汥条捹ഊ
new String bytes (with UTF-16BE charset): ⽳瑯牡来⽥浵污瑥搯汥条捹ഊ
new String bytes (with UTF-16LE charset): 猯潴慲敧支畭慬整⽤敬慧祣਍
new String bytes (with US_ASCII charset): /storage/emulated/legacy
new String bytes (with ISO_8859_1 charset): /storage/emulated/legacy
```

Comment: It turns out to be the problem of my Android Studio. Thanks.